# drawing multiple filled arcs inside oval

Tags: java, swing, graphics

i want to draw the pie menu in java which has 8 pies inside oval all of equal size.
 The problem is when I draw one arc inside oval next arc overlap the previous arc and change its color, but I want 8 equal size filled arcs inside circle with different colors. Can any one tell me how can I achieve this? Here is my code.

```
public class mypanel extends JPanel {

    int mx = 20;
    int my = 20;
    int ms = 120;
    int mg = 120;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.red);
        g2.drawOval(mx, my, 100, 100);
        g2.fillArc(mx, my, 100, 100, 0, 45);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillArc(mx, my, 100, 100, 0, 60);
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillArc(mx, my, 100, 100, 0, 20);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fillArc(mx, my, 100, 100, 0, 80);
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillArc(mx, my, 100, 100, 0, 95);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use [tag:jfreechart]?

Comment: @trashgod can i define events in it. for instance i want to draw rectangle when user click on red color pie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
    Color[] c = {Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, 
                 Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK};
    for(int i=0; i<8; ++i){
        g.setColor(c[i]);
        g.fillArc(x, y, w, h, i*45, 45);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) library includes several basic [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/package-summary.html), including [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html). Click on the class name to see the corresponding [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.62). Any [`CategoryAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/CategoryAnnotation.html) should be applicable, amd there's support for a rich system of [events](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/event/package-summary.html).